# reading file using for, while - behavior

Tags: bash, shell-script, cat, for, shell-builtin

Consider the below scenario

2 vms - 192.168.229.131, 192.168.229.132

Both the vms has it's ip as 192.168.229.151 & 192.168.229.152 in it's `/etc/hosts` file

Say there are around 50 vms like I said above. But as of now, I am considering only the above 2.

I saved ips of the 2 vms in a file named server

```
#cat server
192.168.229.131
192.168.229.132
```

Below is the script

```
#!/bin/bash
cat server | while read line
do
/usr/bin/sshpass -e ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$line << EOF
echo successfully logged in $line
MYIP=$(ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p')
for i in 151 152
do
echo 192.168.229.\$i >> errips
done
for data in `cat errips`
do
echo data currently has $data
grep $data /etc/hosts
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
sed -i "s/$data/$MYIP/g" /etc/hosts
echo "completed"
unset MYIP
rm -rf errips
exit 0
fi
done
EOF
done
```

Below is the output

```
root@master:~# ./script
cat: errips: No such file or directory
successfully logged in 192.168.229.131
cat: errips: No such file or directory
successfully logged in 192.168.229.132
```

Why does the for loop after logging in the server is getting executed before logging in?

I tried using the below instead of 'for'

```
cat errips |while read line
echo line currently has $line
```

In this case, I found that line is still taking the IP from server file in localhost, whereas it should read it from errips file of the server i remotely logged in.

Output was

```
line currently has 192.168.229.131
line currently has 192.168.229.132
```

whereas I expected that it should read the values in file "errips" and output should be something like below

```
line currently has 192.168.229.151
line currently has 192.168.229.151
```

Now, I tried below command

```
cat errips |while read data
echo data currently has $data
```

In this case, the output was empty for the value data

```
data currently has 
data currently has
```

How would I read the file "errips" in my remote server line by line, and grep for the line in /etc/hosts and then execute the if loop, which will replace the wrong ip with right ip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to single quote your here document limit string, otherwise parameter substitution will be enabled. This should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat server | while read line
do
  /usr/bin/sshpass -e ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@$line <<'EOF'
  echo successfully logged in $line
  MYIP=$(ifconfig | sed -En 's/127.0.0.1//;s/.*inet (addr:)?(([0-9]*\.){3}[0-9]*).*/\2/p')
  for i in 151 152
  do
    echo 192.168.229.$i >> errips
  done
  for data in `cat errips`
  do
    echo data currently has $data
    grep $data /etc/hosts
    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
      sed -i "s/$data/$MYIP/g" /etc/hosts
      echo "completed"
      unset MYIP
      rm -rf errips
      exit 0
    fi
  done
EOF
done
```

Notice the single quotes around EOF. To further illuminate, try the following:

```
/usr/bin/sshpass -e ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@<your_ip> 'k=1; echo $k'
/usr/bin/sshpass -e ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@<your_ip> "k=1; echo $k"
/usr/bin/sshpass -e ssh -t -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@<your_ip> "k=1; echo \$k"
```

Comment: Awesome.. it worked...

so, behavior is same when using either double quotes or no quotes.. I tried the 3 commands you have given and found that when I am using double or no quotes, it's taking the value of k as stored in my server and not as i have declared in the command before it.. Thank you so much

Comment: single quoting is not necessary - *any* quoting works. `<<"EOF"` or `<<\EOF` work just as well.